# How to keep function(dset,group) unchanged in R

Tags: r

```
x<- c(62, 60, 63, 59, 63, 67)
grp1<-factor(rep(1:2))
grp2<-rep(1:3)
dat <-data.frame(x,grp1,grp2)

aaa<-function(dset,group) {
  if (length(levels(group))==2) {
    print("ccc")
  }
  else {
    print("ddd")
  }
}
```

I run `aaa(dset=dat,group="grp1")`, but the result is not `"ccc"`. How to revise the `aaa` function contents and keep `aaa(dset=dat,group="grp1")` unchanged?

my answer:

```
aaa<-function(dset,group) {
  grp<-dset[,c(group)]
  if (length(levels(grp))==2) {
    print("ccc")
  }
  else {
   print("ddd")
  }
}

aaa(dset=dat,group="grp1")
```

Comment: Please read some introductory material on `R`. There are many options available on the web.

Comment: Can you tell which introductory material on R to solve my question?

Comment: @Urbano,In my this question.I want to keep aaa(dset=dat,group="grp1") unchanged. so it was not duplicated.

Comment: @stata it is the same problem: "grp1" is a character vector of length one, not the column of name "grp1". By the way: `levels(dset[,group])`

Comment: @Urbano, Perhaps you don't know how to slove my this question,but this question must have an answer. If I have it,I will post it.

Comment: good lord, I just gave you the answer in the comment above: *"grp1" is a character vector of length one, not the column of name "grp1". The answer is `levels(dset[,group])`*

Comment: @Urbano,  Transform "grp1" to grp1 inside function would be a solution.

Comment: "How to store t or F value and P value in data frame" is not an answer of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function needs to know the context of `group` (namely that it is a subset of `dset`):

```
aaa <- function(dset,group) {
  if (length(levels(dset[,group])) == 2) {  #this is different
    print("ccc")
  } else {
    print("ddd")
  }
}
```